# Standard way of representing selection in flowcharts

Tags: flowchart

Okay, so I need know which of below flowcharts has the accepted *'standard'* when it comes to representing **selection**.

AFAIK both are accurate, but which one has the standard representation?

**Method 1,**

[image: Method 1]

**Method 2,**

[image: Method 2]

Answer (score 0):

I would say that "Method 2" is a *standard way* of showing this selection flowchart, as a decision (diamond) doesn't usually have both boolean outputs leading to the same point.